# Hotkeys for SpeedFan 4.47

Tags: windows, controls, gpu

Is there a way to get control of the buttons on the main window of SpeedFan for controlling CPU and GPU speed? I have something like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3L245.png].

Would love to get access to up/down buttons for controlling my GPU speed. Anything similar on the net already? It would be nice to put some keyboard hotkeys for controlling that speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for this purpose.

Comment: Never worked with autohotkey. Solution to the problem with code or steps to do something like in the question? If you have no time for that, I'll try in the coming days.

Comment: First of all read the docs and work from the examples.

Comment: Thanks David, got a proff from you for possibility of doing that with autohotkey. Thanks Sirko and John for editing. Sry for this noob question, was ignorant but I'm still learning.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Fxk0DCyp Hope it help someone.